# How to merge audio and two video file in ffmpeg?

Tags: android, audio, video

I want to merge 2 videos and 1 audio file using ffmpeg in android. Audio should start from the beginning

Comment: how do you want them to be merged?

Comment: do you already add the ffmpeg wrapper for it ?

Comment: For example merge 2 videos first then merge audio, audio should start from the beginning.

Comment: Yes I am using : https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Comment: how doyou want to merge videos? one after another?

Comment: yes. and audio will merge from the beginning

Answer (score 2):

merge two videos

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid]' -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast output1.mp4
```

then merge audio with video output video

```
ffmpeg -i output1.mp4 -i audio.mp3 finalout.mp4
```

these are the command which is use in standarad ffmpeg libraries. I think you need to replace `ffmpeg -i` with `-y -i` to exceute it using that wrapper

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is there any way I can use only one command to perform these task?

Comment: if u want u can use pipe for it. add '|' in-between of these two commands. I didn't try it. I think it should work for u

Comment: @MdWahiduzzamanKhan try adding 3 inputs to first command (_eg:_ add `-i audio.mp3` after those two other `.mp4` files). If lucky it might work.